# newInstance in class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement android introduction library in one of my application located [here](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro). I have followed instruction as given in library page. When I try to use R. for text and image reference, when I add more than 3 R. reference I am getting error like

```
The method newInstance(CharSequence, CharSequence, int, int) in the type AppIntroFragment is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int)
```

My Class is like below

```
public void init(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_1, R.string.description_1, R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("hi", "hello", R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("hi", "hello", R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
    setSeparatorColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

    // Hide Skip/Done button.
    showSkipButton(true);
    setProgressButtonEnabled(true);

    // Turn vibration on and set intensity.
    // NOTE: you will probably need to ask VIBRATE permisssion in Manifest.
    setVibrate(true);
    setVibrateIntensity(30);
}

private void loadMainActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSkipPressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment);
    loadMainActivity();
}
@Override
public void onDonePressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onDonePressed(currentFragment);
    loadMainActivity();
}

public void getStarted(View v){
    loadMainActivity();
}
```

What should I do for solve the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_1, R.string.description_1, R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

to this

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.title_1), getString(R.string.description_1), R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

The constructor expects a CharSequence but you are passing a int.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below line

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_1, R.string.description_1, R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

with

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(getResources().getStringR.string.title_1), getResources().getString(R.string.description_1), R.drawable.rateme, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Comment: its showing as "The method getColor(int) from the type Resources is deprecated " and still error like "The method newInstance(CharSequence, CharSequence, int, int) in the type AppIntroFragment is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, Drawable, int)" :(